# Is Landau free energy really the free energy?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, statistical-mechanics, phase-transition, critical-phenomena

I recall reading in Negele&Orland's book that *Landau free energy* function is not really the free energy that one obtains from the partition function $$F = -\frac{1}{\beta}\log Z.$$ Indeed, the real free energy is already averaged over all possible states and its expansion will never produce a nice shape with multiple minima, used in Landau's analysis of phase transitions.

**Question**
Is Landau energy just a useful theoretical conjecture or is there a principled way of constructing it from a partition function? Examples will be appreciated.

Comment: There is a good discussion in Section 5.6.2 of [Goldenfeld's book](https://www.amazon.com/Lectures-Transitions-Renormalization-Frontiers-Physics/dp/0201554097).

Answer (score 1):

**Alternative definitions of *free energy:***
*Microcanonical ensemble*
Given the density-of-states $\Omega(E)$, we have (taking $k_B=1$)
$$
S(E) = \log \Omega(E),\\
\frac{1}{T}=\frac{\partial S(E)}{\partial E},\\
F(E)=E-TS(E)
$$

*Canonical ensemble*
$$
Z=\sum_n e^{-\frac{E_n}{T}}=\int dE \Omega(E)e^{-\frac{E}{T}}=
\int dE e^{-\frac{E-T\log\Omega(E)}{T}}=\\\int dE e^{-\frac{F(E)}{T}}=e^{-\frac{F_0}{T}}
$$
When taking the thermodynamic limit, the integral can be evaluated using the steepest descent method, which gives
$$
F_0=\min_{E}F(E)
$$

In other words, the *free energy* in canonical ensemble (which is meant by Negele&Orland cited in the OP) is actually the *minimum free energy* in terms of that of the microcanonical ensemble. Calling Landau function *free energy* certainly implies the microcanonical definition, which si used in many physical/chemical methods aiming at free energy minimization.