# Why is the Landau free energy minimized for the order parameter?

Tags: statistical-mechanics

Suppose we have a system which can take different states, characterized by energy $E$ and degeneracy $\gamma(E)$. The energy of each state is characterized by an order parameter $r$, such that $E=E(r)$. By using the microcanonical ensemble one finds that each state has an entropy of $S=S(r)$.

In my exercise I have an explicit example of such an situation (Two lattices (a and b), filled with two different atoms (A and B) with different interaction energies, r being a measure for how much A atoms are on lattice a). The question says that the physically realized value of the order parameter $r$ fullfills the condition

$$\frac{\partial F(T,r)}{\partial r}=\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(E(r)-TS(r)\right)\overset{!}{=}0$$

and asks to find the physical value of $r$. The calculation is easy. But why is this condition valid? Is it related with the maximum entropy principle ($\textrm{tr}(\rho \ln\rho)$ maximized under $\textrm{tr}(\rho)=1$) which lead to the micro-canoncial ensemble in the first place? I cant directly relate these, as there we assumed the energy to be fixed. Now it seems like the energy can arbitrarily vary with the parameter $r$. Why is the free energy minimized with respect to $r$?

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, minimization of *free energy* is equivalent to maximizing entropy, applied to the specific ensemble. Having said that, one must note that here $F$ is not the free energy, but *Landau free energy*, whereas $r$ are not microstates, but macrostates (more precisely - the order parameter). That the realized values of the order parameter correspond to the minima of the Landau free energy follows from its very definition.

To quote the [Goldenfeld's book](https://books.google.fr/books/about/Lectures_On_Phase_Transitions_And_The_Re.html?id=WWAsAAAAYAAJ&redir_esc=y):
"**Landau theory** *postulates* that we can write down a function $L$ known as the **Landau free energy**, or sometimes **the Landau functional**, which depends on the coupling constants $\{K_i\}$ and the order parameter $\eta$. $L$ has the property that the state of the system is specified by the absolute minimum (i.e. global) of $L$ in respect to $\eta$."

**Update**
See [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/652426/247642) for possible ambiguity in what is called "free energy".

Comment: Can you point me to any literature discussing this defnition in detail? This definition of the order parameter as the minimum of landau free energy is not obvious to me.

Comment: It is not a property of the order parameter, but the property of the Landau functional - I added a relevant quote. Landau theory is a phenomenological theory, i.e. it is not derived from the partition function (although sometimes one can do such a derivation).

Comment: Landau in *Statistical physics* also points out that $\eta$ is not a real variable, since its true value is determined by the minimum of the thermodynamic potential (i.e. the Landau functional).